# Find maximum id value in a deeply nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have an tree data structure with each object containing children:

```
const data = {
  id: 1,
  name: "John",
  parent_id: null,
  children: [{
      id: 2,
      name: "Tess",
      parent_id: 1,
      children: []
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Tom",
      parent_id: 1,
      children: [{
          id: 4,
          name: "Harry",
          parent_id: 3,
          children: [{
            id: 7,
            name: "Thabo",
            parent_id: 4,
            children: []
          }]
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Mary",
          parent_id: 3,
          children: []
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "Madge",
          parent_id: 3,
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Before I can add a new object to the tree, I need to determine the highest `id` value currently used, so I can assign the next available number as `id` for the new user.

To do this I created a new variable with an initial value of 0. Then I iterate over each object in the tree, and if the object's `id` is higher than the new id, I assign the new id the current id's value (the idea being taking the final value and adding 1 to get the new id).

```
let newUserID = 0;
const newID = ( root, idKey ) => {
  if ( root.id > idKey ) {
    idKey = root.id;
  }
  root.children.forEach( ( obj ) => {
    newID( obj, idKey );
  });
  return idKey;
}

newUserID = newID( data, newUserID );

console.log( newUserID );
```

I expected this to return the highest `id` in the tree as the final value, but what actually happens is that, while the new id does increase until it matches the maximum value, it then starts decreasing again, ending on 1.

This can be seen in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kokkieh/samxqgn2/19/) which includes some logging to show the value of the new ID at different points in the function.

I've since solved the issue using a different approach (extracting the `id` values to a new array, and using `Math.max()` to find the highest value), but I'd like to understand why my initial approach didn't work as expected. I can see the `idKey` value is being updated, but then the previous value gets passed back on the recursive call, but I don't know why that's happening or how to prevent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as to why your code is broken: You just missed an assignment.  Where you have

```js
   newID( obj, idKey );
```

you are ignoring the resulting value.  You need to assign it back to `idKey`:

```js
    idKey = newID( obj, idKey );
```

That will solve your problem.  We should also note that the variable name `newUserID` is a bit of a misnomer, since it's *not* the the new one you will use but the highest one found.  Perhaps `highestUserID` would be less confusing?

However, we should point out that this can be written much more simply, using `Math .max` to do the heavy lifting and a dollop of recursion.  Here's how I might write this:

```js
const maxId = ({id, children = []}) =>
  Math .max (id, ... children .map (maxId))

const data = {id: 1, name: "John", parent_id: null, children: [{id: 2, name: "Tess", parent_id: 1, children: []}, {id: 3, name: "Tom", parent_id: 1, children: [{id: 4, name: "Harry", parent_id: 3, children: [{id: 7, name: "Thabo", parent_id: 4, children: []}]}, {id: 5, name: "Mary", parent_id: 3, children: []}, {id: 6, name: "Madge", parent_id: 3, children: []}]}]}

console .log (maxId (data))
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something obvious. And point taken on the variable name - it should be descriptive of what it actually is.

Thanks also for the alternative solution. I did end up using `Math.max` in the end, but using `forEach` to iterate through the arrays. Still figuring out how to use the `map()` method instead :)

Comment: Very nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

Simply assign the returned value of the recursive call to `idKey` :

```js
let newUserID = 0;
const newID = ( root, idKey ) => {
  if ( root.id > idKey ) {
    idKey = root.id;
  }
  root.children.forEach( ( obj ) => {
    idKey = newID( obj, idKey ); // <--------
  });
  return idKey;
}

newUserID = newID( data, newUserID );

console.log( newUserID );
```

Without this assignment, no matter how much you recurse, the value returned will depend only on the result of the `if` statement at the top. This explains the logs you were getting.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something obvious I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to solve this. Like below

```js
const data = {
  id: 1,
  name: "John",
  parent_id: null,
  children: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Tess",
      parent_id: 1,
      children: [],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Tom",
      parent_id: 1,
      children: [
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Harry",
          parent_id: 3,
          children: [
            {
              id: 7,
              name: "Thabo",
              parent_id: 4,
              children: [],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Mary",
          parent_id: 3,
          children: [],
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "Madge",
          parent_id: 3,
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const findMax = (value) => {
  let max = -Infinity;
  const _findMax = (data) => {
    if (max < data.id) max = data.id;
    data.children.forEach(_findMax);
  };
  _findMax(value);
  return max;
};

console.log(findMax(data));
```

Comment: I did do something similar to this in the end, but thanks for the alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const data = {id: 1,name: 'John',parent_id: null,children: [{ id: 2, name: 'Tess', parent_id: 1, children: [] },{id: 3,name: 'Tom',parent_id: 1,children: [{id: 4,name: 'Harry',parent_id: 3,children: [{ id: 7, name: 'Thabo', parent_id: 4, children: [] }],},{ id: 5, name: 'Mary', parent_id: 3, children: [] },{ id: 6, name: 'Madge', parent_id: 3, children: [] },],},],}
const arr = [...JSON.stringify(data).matchAll(/"id":(\d+)/g)].map(([, n]) => +n)
const result = Math.max(...arr)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Using RegEx to extract the id values from the nested objects is an interesting approach. Wouldn't have thought of that. Thank you :)